# Ruby regex count matched elements in the array of digits

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I have a string:

```
'my_array1: ["1445","374","1449","378"], my_array2: ["1445","374", "1449","378"]'
```

I need to match all sets of digits from `my_array2: [...]` and count how many of them there.

I need to do something like this with regex and ruby MatchData

```
string = 'my_array1: ["1445","374", "1449","378"], my_array2: ["1445","374", "1449","378"]'
matches = string.match(/my_array2\:\s[\[,]\"(\d+)\"/)
count_matches = matches.size
```

Expected result should be 4.
What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I would use [this regex](http://rubular.com/r/LSOZnNU7z6) to match the digit-only arrays. It won't work with mixed type arrays.

Comment: Your string is invalid. You haven't escaped `"` correctly. It is not clear what it means.

Comment: This smells like an XY-question. Where does that string come from?

Comment: I just changed that string to single quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed that the content of `my_array2` is always numeric you could simply use split twice. First you splitby `my_array2: ["` and then split by `,`. This should give you the amount of items you are after.

If you are not guaranteed that, you could still split by `my_array2` and instead of splitting again, you use a pattern such as `"\d+"` (or `"\d+(\.\d+)?` if you have floating point values) and count.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/bR1xJ8/1).